# Почему при расчёте хеша в классах String и Integer(в этих точно) используется именно 31

Tags: java, хеширование

Почему при расчёте хеша в классах String и Integer(в этих точно) используется именно 31

например (но могло быть и другое число)
return x*31 +y;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/299748

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блох в своей книге писал: выбрали 31, потому что это число нечётное и простое. Нечётное -  младший бит 1 и при сдвиге влево (умножение на 2), при переполнении что-нибудь да останется. Простое - традиционно. Плюс к тому умножение на 31 можно представить как 31 * i == (i << 5) - i, возможна оптимизация (сдвигать и вычитать быстрее).